# Sumifs in Crystal

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm working on a database that basically looks like this (in its simplest form):

{Phase} {Code} {Qty}

Example:

{Qty} for {Phase}="R" and {Code}="Nat" = 0

{Qty} for {Phase}="F" and {Code}="Nat" = 5

{Qty} for {Phase}="R" and {Code}="Int" = 10

{Qty} for {Phase}="F" and {Code}="Int" = 15

I am trying to get a result to show me the Qty for phase "R" and Code "Nat" (where R is <> 0) otherwise give me the qty for phase "F". So for the above example I would get an answer = 5 for Nat (because qty for phase R is 0) and an answer of 10 where the code is Int (because qty for phase R <> 0)

I have used three formula fields to do this:

1: if ({PHASE}="F" and {CODE}="NAT") then {QTY} else 0

2: if ({PHASE}="R" and {Code}="NAT") then {QTY} else 0

3: if {2} = 0 then {1} else {2}

Formula fields 1 & 2 come up with the correct amounts. However formula field {3} returns both phases. For example Code "Int" Phase "R" shows as qty = 25 instead of qty = 10.

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to group by {table.code} because this is not a one-row calculation, but needs to be a calculation over each code for 2+ phases (meaning 2+ rows of data).
2. Create a formula with two variables that will store the values of each phase, F and R. This formula needs to go in the Details section of the report.

   ```
   whileprintingrecords;
   numbervar Fqty;
   numbervar Rqty;

   if {table.phase}="F" then Fqty:={table.qty}
   else Rqty:={table.qty};
   ```
3. Now, in the group footer, you can reference both quantity values via the variables.

   ```
   whileprintingrecords;
   numbervar Fqty;
   numbervar Rqty;

   if Fqty=0 then Rqty else Fqty
   ```

And you're done. Don't forget to reset the two variables in the group header so you don't carry the quantity over between different codes.